# "Exception in thread "Animation Thread" error when using Processing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class, exception, processing

I have a created a very simple processing sketch in eclipse with classes.Eclipse says the code contains no errors, only warnings, however it fails at runtime and the console displays the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at processing.core.PApplet.ellipse(PApplet.java:12174)
at assignment.Tracking.display(Tracking.java:15)
at assignment.Assignment.draw(Assignment.java:16)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code is the following:

```
package assignment; 
import processing.core.*;   
public class Assignment extends PApplet {

     Tracking tracking;

     public void setup() {
         size(500, 500);
         tracking = new Tracking();
     }  

     public void draw() {
         tracking.display();
     }
 }
```

And the code for the Tracking class is:

```
    package assignment;
    import processing.core.*;  

    public class Tracking extends PApplet
    {
      int test;

      public Tracking() {
      test = 100;
      }

      void display(){
          ellipse(test, test, test, test);
      }
    }
```

I believe I have imported the necessary processing .jar files. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you do the setup in the `Assignment` class, but calls `ellipse()` from the `Tracking` class. Note that `Assignment` and `Tracking` are two different `PApplet`s. You call `size(500, 500)` in `Assignment`, but `Tracking` has no defined size.